# how to fetch data from array by indexing in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

> This is my Json file and i don't understand how to fetch data and set
> the Image in our SwiftUI code. please help me resolve this problem.

> And this is My Model, is this model correct?
> This is My API and wants to fetch only value images array

```
import Foundation


public struct BannerImages {
    public let images: [String]

    public init(images: [String]) {
        self.images = images
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't take it the wrong way, but it sounds like what you need is a tutorial or lesson on Swift and SwiftUI. YouTube is full of those, I particularly enjoy this guy https://www.youtube.com/c/PaulHudson. I think if you watch a few videos and still can't solve it, you'll at the minimum gain the terms and vocabulary to hon in on the actual question you have.

Comment: The Model us fine but you haven't shown any attempt to solve you own issue. Give it a try and we can help troubleshoot. Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this approach to fetch your `images` and display them in a View:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Fetching the data...")
            List (vm.images, id: \.self) { url in
                AsyncImage(url: URL(string: url)) { image in
                    image
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 111, height: 111)
                } placeholder: {
                    ProgressView()
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            await vm.getData()
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var images = [String]()
    
    func getData() async {
        guard let url = URL(string: "apiurl") else { return }
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            Task{@MainActor in
                let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse.self, from: data)
                self.images = results.images
            }
        } catch {
            print("---> error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

struct APIResponse: Codable {
    let images: [String]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
1. First you need to have a variable with data type of Data like this: var imageData: Data?

2. Then you have to fetch the image data from the link in the array like this:
func getImageData() {
        // Check image url isnt nill
        guard imageUrl(your image url) != nil else {
            return
        }
        // Download the data for the image
        let url = URL(string: imageUrl(your image url)!)
        if let url = url {
            let session = URLSession.shared
            let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if error == nil {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.imageData = data
                    }
                }
            }
            dataTask.resume()
        }
    }

3. Once this is done go to the view file where you want to display the image and create 

let uiImage = UIImage(data: put the var in which you stored the image data in previous step ?? Data())
 
Image(uiImage: uiImage ?? UIImage())
```